# Gamma function: Mathematica disagrees with Wolfram Alpha

Tags: numerics, special-functions

When I enter

```
N[Gamma[2, -40]]
```

into my Mathematica notebook, I get

```
-9.18003*10^18 + 1124.23 i
```

However, [Wolfram Alpha will give me a real expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N%5BGamma%5B2,%20-40%5D%20%5D). Why do these two numbers disagree - and which one is correct?

Comment: It is a precision issue. Use arbitrary precision rather than machine precision:  `N[Gamma[2, -40], 20]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Apparently I also have to wrap `N[x, 20]` around `Gamma` whenever I use Gamma in longer equations, if I want to kill those imaginary terms in the result? Sounds somewhat suspicious to me.

Comment: Using arbitrary precision causes Mma to track and control the precision. Look at `N[Gamma[2, -40], 6]`.  You could also force the `Gamma` function to evaluate before asking for the numerical approximation: `Evaluate[Gamma[2, -40]] // N`

Comment: @BobHanlon the `Evaluate, //` chain also yields an imaginary component

Comment: Must be a version difference. There is no imaginary component with `version 11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)`

Comment: @BobHanlon If you answer with this set of comments I'm happy to accept and close this matter :)

Comment: In v10 `Evaluate` doesn't do anything,and you always end up with a "zero" imaginary part needing `Chop` regardless of precision.

Comment: notice BTW from definition this case is `Integrate[ t Exp[-t ] , {t, -40, Infinity}]` or `-39Exp[40]`  ( I assume v11 evaluates to that ? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a precision issue. If you use [`arbitrary precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionCalculations.html) rather than machine precision, Mathematica will track and control the precision.

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"  *)

N[Gamma[2, -40]]

(*  -9.18003*10^18 + 1124.23 I  *)

N[Gamma[2, -40], 30] // Chop

(*  -9.18002540664377943090809651921*10^18  *)
```

This [`Gamma`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Gamma.html) function can be evaluated exactly using [`FunctionExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html)

```
Gamma[2, -40] // FunctionExpand

(*  -39 E^40  *)

Gamma[2, -40] // FunctionExpand // N

(*  -9.18003*10^18  *)
```

A later version does not have these problems

```
$Version

(*  "11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"  *)

Gamma[2, -40]

(*  -39 E^40  *)

Gamma[2, -40] // N

(*  -9.18003*10^18  *)
```